# get current system serial number in python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to get system serial number using python.

Below is the command to get serial number using command prompt:

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

Is there any python library to get the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can run shell commands via [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('wmic bios get serialnumber').decode("utf-8")
```

You should get something like

> SerialNumber  \r\r\n< cencored >       \r\r\n\r\r\n'

For more see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)